# Different exit codes

Tags: bash, shell, exit-code

I'm trying to grep for a version number from my subversion command, so that I can check we have the write subversion module loaded in a bash script.

Interactively, this is an example use:

```
> svn --version | head -n1 | grep -q '1.7'; echo $?
0
```

However, when I put this same line (and nothing else) in a script and run the script:

```
> ./setup_svn.sh
1
```

Also, the script runs noticeably faster than the interactive shell command. Does anyone have ideas of what I might be missing that explains this result?

---

**Edit**

It turns out that my interactive bash script was using the wrong svn command. Not sure exactly why, but I think that might be a question for the Unix StackExchange.

It's almost certainly to do with the module system on our workstations, running interactively I get:

```
> module list
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
...
12) subversion/1.7.7    
> which svn
/usr/bin/svn
> svn --version
svn, version 1.7.7 (r1393599)
...
```

Running in the script, I get:

```
> ./setup_svn.sh
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
...
12) subversion/1.7.7    
/usr/bin/svn
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
...
```

**Further edit**

It seems that if I start a new shell, I also get the same issues:

```
> bash
> module list
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
...
12) subversion/1.7.7
> svn --version
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
```

I think I'll find out what our module system does to the environment and use that to work out what's going wrong.

Comment: What happens when you remove the grep from the script? Do you get the same output from `svn --version` as you do on the command line?

Comment: If I were you I'd start by breaking that pipeline up into individual commands and testing their behaviour interactively and in scripts.

Comment: I tried that exact setup and each time (interactive or in the script) it gave me `0`, and both run just as fast (at least by human standards: a fraction of a second). A `1` code means some command in the pipeline didn't succeed. Are you sure you have exactly the same thing in the shell script as you typed at the command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

I know it will not correct the issue, but I think the head command is useless. You can use the --quiet option.

```
$ svn --version --quiet
1.7.5
```

---

EDIT:

If it's a semicolon issue as mentioned by konsolebox, you can also use this syntax :

```
echo $(svn --version --quiet | grep -q '1.7')$?
```

Comment: Aye, I was using this before, but took it out, since I wanted to try to eliminate this as a source of error. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

It could be how the shell handles the semicolon. Try to place in two lines.

```
#!/bin/sh
svn --version | head -n1 | grep -q '1.7'
echo "$?"
```

If you're in bash also, make sure that pipefail is not enabled:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -u -o pipefail
svn --version | head -n1 | grep -q '1.7'
echo "$?"
```